# MiniBatchKMeans OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer?

Tags: python, types, scikit-learn, infinity

I am trying to find the right number of clusters, `k`, according to silhouette scores using `sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans`.

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer

docs = ['hello monkey goodbye thank you', 'goodbye thank you hello', 'i am going home goodbye thanks', 'thank you very much sir', 'good golly i am going home finally']

vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

for k in range(5):
    model = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = k)
    model.fit(X)
```

And I receive this error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 1279
    0, n_samples - 1, init_size)
DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. Please call randint(0, 4 + 1) instead
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 3, in <module>
    model.fit(X)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 1300, in fit
    init_size=init_size)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 640, in _init_centroids
    x_squared_norms=x_squared_norms)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 88, in _k_init
    n_local_trials = 2 + int(np.log(n_clusters))
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

I know the `type(k)` is `int`, so I don't know where this issue is coming from. I can run the following just fine, but I can't seem to iterate through integers in a list, even though the `type(2)` is equal to `k = 2; type(k)`

```
model = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = 2)
model.fit(X)
```

Even running a different `model` works:

```
>>> model = KMeans(n_clusters = 2)
>>> model.fit(X)
KMeans(copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_clusters=2, n_init=10,
    n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto', random_state=None, tol=0.0001,
    verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's analyze your code:

- `for k in range(5)` returns the following sequence:

  - `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`
- `model = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = k)` inits model with `n_clusters=k`
- Let's look at the first iteration:

  - `n_clusters=0` is used
  - Within the optimization-code (look at the output):
  - `int(np.log(n_clusters))`
  - = `int(np.log(0))`
  - = `int(-inf)`
  - ERROR: no infinity definition for integers!
  - -> casting floating-point value of -inf to int not possible!

Setting `n_clusters=0` does not make sense!

Comment: Outstanding explanation. Thanks for taking me all the way through the traceback.