# KMeans - OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

Below are the top 5 rows of the variables, I am using for the KMeans to find the optimal no of clusters-

```
store_code  PinCode sale_price_after_promo
0   2655    453441.0    55.00
1   2655    999999.0    30.00
2   2655    400064.0    418.95
3   2615    400099.0    70.00
4   2655    474001.0    34.20
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-3802a2b79f71> in <module>()
      2 for i in range(0,11):
      3     kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', random_state=42)
----> 4     kmeans.fit(X)
      5     wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
      6 plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)

OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

How to get rid of this error even I have tried using various combinations of variables but still getting the same error?

Comment: The problem, most probably, is that you are setting the number of clusters to 0. Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051170/minibatchkmeans-overflowerror-cannot-convert-float-infinity-to-integer

Comment: @DimKoim But I have defined a range from 0 to 10. So how to correct this error?

Comment: Do that: for i in range(1,11). Let me know.

Comment: @DimKoim Thanks. Changed the range from 1 to 11 and it worked out.

Comment: Nice! Upvote my answer then!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DimKoim I cannot as I don't have the reputation of more than 15.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot run k-means with k=0 clusters.

Also, your data seems very inappropriate for k-means.

It absolutely makes no sense to run k-means on identifier attributes such as "storeId" and "pinCode".

Answer (score 2):

Basically we can't run KMean cluster with `k=0`

Solution is:-

```
for i in range(1,11):
```

> I mean use k in range(1 to 11) not in range(0,11)

*It will solve your problem.*

Answer (score 0):

I tried `for i in range(1,11):` but still it did not run properly. But instead mine was solved by using

```
for i in range(1,12):
```